# Regex match "target string"

Tags: c#, regex

Environment: Visual Studio 2008 SP1

How can I write the following regex?

I'm trying to get to **'target string**. The pattern is any string between [name]=' '

```
/*Input String*/
SET [blah] = 'AE', [blah] = 'A1A', [number] = 004 WHERE [name]='target string'


/*Current Regex*/
(?<=[?name]?=).*(?=\')

/*Current Results*/
'AE', [blah] = 'A1A', [number] = 004 WHERE [name]='target string

/*Desired Results*/
'target string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
(?<=\[name]=).*?(?=')
```

Or if the target string has to be returned without the leading ('):

```
(?<=\[name]=').*?(?=')
```

Note: I assume that the target string does not have escaped apostrophes ('').

---

EDIT: This does the trick with the escaped apostrophes:

```
(?<=\[name]=)(''|.)+?(?='([^']|$))
```

It will find "`'John''s pub`" in

```
SET [blah] = 'AE', [blah] = 'A1A', [number] = 004 WHERE [name]='John''s pub'
```

Comment: The OP's regex had the square-brackets as optional, and I'm fairly certain that that was intentional: this looks like a fragment of a SQLServer `UPDATE` statement, where field-names can-but-need-not be wrapped in square-brackets.

Comment: Yes, ? would make the brackes optional.

Comment: Not "would" make, "does" make. (I'm saying that I think your proposed regex is wrong.)

Comment: I've tested it on the example given in the question. It gives the desired result. With "would" I meant "if it was requested".

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your square-brackets, or else they'll be misinterpreted as creating a character class. That is, you need:

```
(?<=\[?name\]?=).*(?=\')
```

I'd also recommend changing `.*` to the more explicit `'[^']*`, just so you don't risk catching anything *after* the target string; and Tim Pietzcker points out (in a now-deleted comment) that you can write `'` instead of `\'` (near the end of the regex); so:

```
(?<=\[?name\]?=)'[^']*(?=')
```